# Custom color for each category name

Tags: categories, color-picker

I have tested several plugins and none is perfect solution. I would like to have simple solution so user can select the color for the Category name which will be the actual color of the text/link like in the example bellow. Have been playing around with this and can't find a proper way to include this into my own theme. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this Follow these easy step:

1. Add field for color To Add/Edit category Screen using hooks [category_add_form_fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/) and [category_edit_form_fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_edit_form_fields/)

   ```
   add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'my_category_fields', 10, 2);
   add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'my_category_fields', 10, 2);
   function my_category_fields($term) {
           $cat_color = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'cat_color', true);
           if($cat_color == '') $cat_color = '#000000'; // Default black color

   ?>
   <tr class="form-field">
           <th valign="top" scope="row"><label for="cat_color"><?php _e('Color code'); ?></label></th>
           <td>
               <input type="color" size="40" value="<?php echo esc_attr($cat_color); ?>" id="cat_color" name="cat_color"><br/>
               <span class="description"><?php _e('Please select a color'); ?></span>
           </td>
       </tr>
   <?php
   }
   ```
2. Save field for color submitted from Add/Edit category Screen using hooks  [edited_category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/edited_$taxonomy) and [create_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_taxonomy/)

   ```
   add_action('edited_category', 'save_my_category_fields', 10, 2);
   add_action('create_category', 'save_my_category_fields', 10, 2);

   function save_my_category_fields($term_id) {
      if (!isset($_POST['cat_color'])) {
          return;
      }

   update_term_meta($term_id, 'cat_color', sanitize_text_field($_POST['cat_color']));

   }
   ```
3. Finally use the saved color by using [get_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)

   ```
   get_term_meta($term_id, 'cat_color', true);   // Replace $term_id with your own
   ```

For example,

```
<?php
$categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    $color = get_term_meta($category->term_id, 'cat_color', true);
?>
     <li>
       <span class="label" style="background: <?php echo $color ; ?>">
          <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>" >
             <?php echo $category->name ; ?>
         </a>
      </span>
    </li>
<?php 
   }
 ?>
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: I am sorry for getting back so late. I just had time to test today. I have hard time replicating this. Maybe due my newbie Wordpress knowledge. I am receiving error: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_category_field' not found or invalid function name in wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Comment: Sorry for **typo in first block** of code in my answer :  
add_action('category_add_form_fields', '**my_category_field**', 10, 2);
add_action('category_edit_form_fields', '**my_category_field**', 10, 2);
 should be  
add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'my_category_field**s**', 10, 2);
add_action('category_edit_form_fields', my_category_field**s**', 10, 2);  
I have updated the answer. i hope this will work now without fail.

Comment: **UPDATE:** Corrected some more errors in **first block of code**. Now it works on my setup without fail.

Comment: @KostaKostic https://imgur.com/a/YxpZmM4

Comment: For color picker see https://themehybrid.com/weblog/introduction-to-wordpress-term-meta

Comment: The 3rd part just echo the color code saved for a specific term. You can use it  in your theme e.g. `<span class="label" style="background: <?php echo get_term_meta($term_id, 'cat_color', true);   ?>"> </span>`. Its use depend upon the code you use to display categories.

Comment: Thank you for speedy reply. <?php echo get_term_meta($term_id, 'cat_color', true); ?> Did not produce hex code in the source.

Comment: It will work in loop, where categories are displayed. Please check the updated answer. At the end I have added an example. you can use this example code and adjust to fit within your function mentioned in your second last comment `enso_get_post_categories( ' · ' ) `

Comment: For some reason I can't make this work. Theme is calling category name from library/functions/post.php file.

Comment: In case you cannot change theme function, then you can comment out call to that function that function where this functionality is required and adjust code in my answer there to meet your requirements. **Or** you can create your own function based on my code and call it to display categories.

Comment: I am sorry for taking your time, but this did not work for me. Could be due to theme structure for getting category names. Will have to re-think if this should be implemented at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too simple for your problem, but you could have a custom field that allows the user to type in the hex or rgba color code. Just output this inline with the element.

Heres an example using ACF plugin.

```
<span class="label" style="background: <?php the_field('color'); ?>"> </span>
```

Third party ACF plugins also support a color picker, for a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This should be done without plugins.