# Retrieving category's color with get_term_meta

Tags: categories, custom-field

I followed [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/330293/custom-color-for-each-category-name) tutorial to add colors to categories.
However I can't make it work, when I try to use it in my loop nothing happens, I tried multiple versions but none was right.
This is what I tried:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        ?>
        
        <div class="catalogue_item">
            <h2 style="color:<?php
                //This is where i want the category color name
                ;
            ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">lien vers la fiche</a>
            <p>
                <?php foreach ( ( get_the_category() ) as $category ) {
                    echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
                }?>
            </p>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <p> prix: <?php echo (types_render_field( 'price', array() ));?> </p>
            <p> prix2: <?php echo (types_render_field( 'pricet', array() ));?> </p>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

And I cannot find something that works, I'm sorry if this is a dumb one but I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems that you want to fetch the meta for the post. In which case you would want `get_post_meta` which would look something like this:

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'color', true );
```

Change the second value ('color') to whatever you have used for the meta key - I took a wild guess.

Comment: I did not work, after many attempts to understand how to retrieve the term_id and the custom field I ended up with that

<?php $color_cat = the_category_ID($echo = false); ?>
            <div class="catalogue_item">
                <h2 style="background-color:<?php  echo get_term_meta( $color_cat, 'cat_color', true ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

I know it's not clean code but it works... Ty for your help

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is with my answer. You are storing the colour in the term meta, not the post meta.

Comment: Indeed but even with get_term_meta it did not work. Maybe an error I made somewhere else...